# PDO: row name as index of result array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this "old-style" non-PDO MySQL query (the code isn't tightened up, just to show exactly what I mean):

```
<?php
include('db_conn.php'); //Contains the connection info.

$category = 'cars';
$q = "SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `category` = '$category'";
$qResult = mysql_query($q);
$Numq = mysql_numrows($qResult);

$count = 0;
while ($count < $Numq)
{
$ThisID = mysql_result($qResult,$count,"id");
$ThisCaption = mysql_result($qResult,$count,"caption");
echo '<img src="images/'.$ThisID.'.jpg" alt="" />';
echo '<br />'.$ThisCaption.'<br /><br />';
$count++;
}
?>
```

I'd like to re-cast the query in PDO form (which I'm just learning).  I've written this:

```
<?php
//I've set out the connection info format in case there's anything wrong with it...
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=my_host;dbname=my_db_name;charset=UTF-8', 'db_user', 'user_password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); //I prefer to throw PHP errors.
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$category = 'cars';
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `category`=?");
$statement->execute(array($category));
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

while ($result = $statement->fetch()) {
//$result[0] = the ID, $result[1] = the caption...
echo '<img src="images/'.$result[0].'.jpg" alt="" />';
echo '<br />'.$result[1].'<br /><br />';
}
?>
```

... In the "old" non-PDO form I can capture the ID and the caption just by specifying the column name.
... but in the PDO form I have to specify $result[0] and $result[1].
... How can I change the PDO form so that I don't have to explicitly specify ("remember") which member of the array is the ID, and which is the caption, etc (as the "old" method allows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using **`PDO::FETCH_BOTH`** as fetching mode, you'll probably want to use **`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`** -- to fetch your data as an associative array.

Then you can access the members of the array by: `$result['id']`, `$result['caption']`, etc.

PDO supports several interesting fetching modes ; including

- associative-array : the keys of the array will be the column names, as returned from the database ; which is probably what you are used to
- objects ; including instances of the class you specify

To see what's possible, you might want to take a look at the different **`PDO::FETCH_*`** constants -- the list can be found here : [**Predefined Constants**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php).

Comment: @Travesty3 Thanks for your edit :-) I was editing at the same time, and your modifications have been lost for a couple of seconds -- but I've restored them by hand *(hoping I've not forgotten anything)*, thanks to the history ^^

Comment: No problem. Just figured it might be helpful to point that out as well.

Comment: Aha!  So it should be: `<?php
//(Earlier code, same as before).
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($result = $statement->fetch()) {
$ThisID = $result['id'];
$ThisCaption = $result['caption'];
echo '<img src="images/'.$ThisID.'.jpg" alt="" />';
echo '<br />'.$ThisCaption.'<br /><br />';
}
?>`

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Have fun !

Comment: As a side note, am I right in thinking that the prepared statement as written above is immune to sql injection attacks (not sure if this is off topic or not)

Comment: Well, you are using a prepared statement, and not injecting any kind of data *(and not escaping it)* into the SQL query yourself, so I'd say your code looks OK, on the "sql injection" side of things. ;;; you might want to escape the HTML you are outputting, though *(using htmlspecialchars for instance)*, especially if you are not sure what the caption can contain

Comment: @JohnDoe: In your while-loop, do this: `$result = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $result);`

Comment: I'm running ahead of my own brain now :) but yes I will be using _htmlspecialchars_.  I have another example of a query that will fired up from a hyperlink that I want to transform to PDO/prepared statement form, but perhaps I'll put that up as a different question.  Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you Travesty3 for your helpful tip

Answer (score 1):

```
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Specified [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::FETCH_BOTH` is supposed to allow you to access the results both as an associative array and by iterator so that should work. You could try changing it to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and see if that works, but also try explicitly stating the columns in the query, as opposed to using `*`.

Comment: Using * does not prevent PDO from returning results in the form the OP wants (associative array with column names as keys), at least not with FETCH_ASSOC.

Comment: @octern: Agree, it doesn't have anything to do with answering the question, but I do think it's a good idea to avoid using `*`, and instead explicitly state the columns, whenever possible/practical.